# Xbox One Controller not working after xboxdrv drivers are installed

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, games

So I tried using my Xbox One controller but it didn't work. I decided to search around and found that I need drivers so I installed xboxdrv. Even though I started it and made it run perfectly, my controller doesn't seem to do anything. My game detects that the controller is connected, but my controller's light continues to blink and it's not able to do anything. Keep in kind I am using a USB. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `My game detects that the controller is connected` ... are you certain? ... maybe the game is detecting the driver, not the hardware

Comment: Well that might be a possibility. It just shows the controller on there and tells me to press X on my controller to disconnect even though I can't.